# Java Streams filter and replace an item in list if it meets criteria

Tags: java

I am using Java 8 streams and would like to remove an item in my list if multiple items with the same room number are present and use the one with the most current date.

I have this list:

```
final List<TestClass> testClasses = Arrays.asList(
            new TestClass(100L, LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 10)),
            new TestClass(100L, LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 10)),
            new TestClass(101L, LocalDate.of(2020, 7, 20)),
            new TestClass(102L, LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 9)),
            new TestClass(103L, LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 11)),
            new TestClass(104L, LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 13))
    );
```

I would like to filter this list down in a way such that if the roomNumber (first param of TestClass constructor) occurs multiple times in the list then that entry should be removed and the one with the most current date will be saved.

Sample output from above list after filtering:

```
[
       TestClass(100L, LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 10)),
       TestClass(101L, LocalDate.of(2020, 7, 20)),
       TestClass(102L, LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 9)),
       TestClass(103L, LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 11)),
       TestClass(104L, LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 13))
]
```

As you can see the second TestClass object with a roomNumber of 100 has been removed and we are left with the first TestClass object that also has a roomNumber of 100 but we keep it since the date is higher or more recent than the other entry.

I have read through the Java streams documentation and am aware of filtering. Is there a way to achieve this functionality using Java streams? I feel like there is but there may be a way to use this api that I am unaware of.

TIA and please let me know if more information is required :)

EDIT:
This is the attempt that I made. I learned about the groupingBy function and was able to get the TestClasses into a list grouped by their room number. I am not sure where to go from there.

```
 Map<Long, List<TestClass>> c = testClasses.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TestClass::getRoomNumber));
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058670/in-which-cases-stream-operations-should-be-stateful

Comment: what have you tried and how it did not work out? you aware of the filtering method then whats holding you back?

Comment: Please, share your **attempt** and specify the problem you've encountered. Every question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an effort. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: You are probably looking for one of the [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) methods. Group elements by the room number (the result will be a `Map`), then get the record with the latest date in each entry.

Comment: I updated the question to show that I grouped the objects but I am not sure how to filter down the grouped map back into a single list with the highest dates removed if multiple rooms are present

Answer (score 0):

You've made a great attempt! You can continue to process the map by converting each value (a list of `TestClass` instances) to a single `TestClass` instance by getting the maximum value using the date:

```
 List<TestClass> c = testClasses.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TestClass::getRoomNumber))
        .values() // returns the collection of values from the map
        .stream() // converts that collection to a stream
        .map(group -> // converts each item (a list of TestClass for a given room number)
                group.stream() // converts that list to a stream
                        .max( // returns the maximum value of the list using the following Comparator
                                Comparator.comparing(TestClass::getDate)
                                // creates a comparator for TestClass based on calling getDate on each item,
                                // using the natural ordering for LocalDate
                        ) // This returns Optional<TestClass>
        ) // This returns Stream<Optional<TestClass>>
        .filter(Optional::isPresent) // This removes empty Optional values
        .map(Optional::get) // Converts the non-empty Optional to the value it contains
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Collects the resulting stream into a list
```

One point of further clarification: why does `max` return an `Optional<TestClass>`? This handles the case of an empty stream (in other words, a room number in the map with no `TestClass` items), in which case an empty `Optional` is returned. Now, we know that this can't possibly happen, because of the way the data structure is built, but the compiler cannot infer that, so it is required to handle the impossible case of empty values. Strictly speaking, the `filter` part could be eliminated, but having it will ensure the code is robust in the face of some future change that allows empty values to appear.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java Streams toMap function**

***Approach Here:***

You can try the below approach in which i have first `sorted` the `list` by `id` and then `date` in reverse order *(so that the list will have the latest record at top corresponding to each id)* and then using **`Collectors.toMap`** function created a map with key as id and value as the object of TestClass along with the **merger function** `(a, b) -> a`(*which will help in getting the latest value corresponding to each key)* and `TreeMap::new` will give the **sorted** map.

After that, I have created a `new ArrayList` of `TestClass` type with the `values` using `.values` of the map created above.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<TestClass> testClasses = Arrays.asList(
                new TestClass(100L, LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 10)),
                new TestClass(100L, LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 10)),
                new TestClass(101L, LocalDate.of(2020, 7, 20)),
                new TestClass(102L, LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 9)),
                new TestClass(103L, LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 11)),
                new TestClass(104L, LocalDate.of(2020, 2, 13))
        );

        List<TestClass> uniqueListWithLatestData =
            new ArrayList<>(testClasses.stream()
            .sorted((Comparator.comparing(TestClass::id)
                          .thenComparing(TestClass::date).reversed()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(TestClass::id, x -> x,(a, b) -> a, 
                                       TreeMap::new)).values());
             System.out.println(uniqueListWithLatestData);

    }
}
```

**Note:**

Here, I have created a `record` for TestClass for the solution, you can have your own TestClass POJO.*(Records are available from JDK14)*

```
public record TestClass(long id, LocalDate date) {}
```

**Output:**

```
[TestClass[id=100, date=2020-01-10], 
TestClass[id=101, date=2020-07-20], 
TestClass[id=102, date=2020-01-09], 
TestClass[id=103, date=2020-01-11], 
TestClass[id=104, date=2020-02-13]]
```